# what to do with two related questions?

Tags: discussion

There's one of the many logic problems with prisoners and hats for which I have found a nice generalization for the case when hats may be of three or more colors. However I do not know if my answer is optimal or not.

Is it better just to ask a single question on the site, or first to propose the problem asking for the simpler solution and then to make another question asking for possible improvements?